# Mapping ymd_hms time into 15 minute time intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I am looking for a data.table solution to the following question.

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT <- data.table(date = c("2019-01-01 00:03:04", 
                          "2019-01-01 00:07:03",
                          "2019-01-01 00:15:23",
                          "2019-01-01 00:16:28",
                          "2019-01-01 00:21:30"))
DT
         date
1: 2019-01-01 00:03:04
2: 2019-01-01 00:07:03
3: 2019-01-01 00:15:23
4: 2019-01-01 00:16:28
5: 2019-01-01 00:21:30
```

I am looking to map each date into 15 minute interval for each day. So the final dataset would look like:

```
   date                    date_15min_grp
1: 2019-01-01 00:03:04              1
2: 2019-01-01 00:07:03              1
3: 2019-01-01 00:15:23              2
4: 2019-01-01 00:16:28              2
5: 2019-01-01 00:21:30              2
```

The groups would be unique at the day level, so `2019-01-01 00:03:04` and `2019-01-02 00:03:04` would both return values of 1. My current solution is to extract the hour/minute/second component of each day. I would then add the values (after conversion into minutes), divide them by 60, and try to map each value to the nearest "group". But this seems to be slow and inelegant.

A data.table/lubridate would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I’m fairly sure there is a cut method with an interval specification that can be set to “15 min” for POSIXct vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below a solution using `data.table` and `lubridate`

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT[, date_15min_grp := fcase(minute(date) < 15, 1,
                             minute(date) < 30, 2,
                             minute(date) < 45, 3,
                             default = 4)][]
```

- Output

```r
#>                   date date_15min_grp
#> 1: 2019-01-01 00:03:04              1
#> 2: 2019-01-01 00:07:03              1
#> 3: 2019-01-01 00:15:23              2
#> 4: 2019-01-01 00:16:28              2
#> 5: 2019-01-01 00:21:30              2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**AS A FOLLOW-UP TO YOUR COMMENT**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT[, date_15min_grp := fcase(minute(date) < 15, hour(date)*4 + 1,
                             minute(date) < 30, hour(date)*4 + 2,
                             minute(date) < 45, hour(date)*4 + 3,
                             minute(date) < 60, hour(date)*4 + 4)][]
```

- Output

```r
#>                   date date_15min_grp
#> 1: 2019-01-01 00:03:04              1
#> 2: 2019-01-01 00:07:03              1
#> 3: 2019-01-01 00:15:23              2
#> 4: 2019-01-01 00:16:28              2
#> 5: 2019-01-01 00:21:30              2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my description. This is not just base on minutes but also based on hours. So `2019-01-01 00:21:30` and `2019-01-01 01:21:30` should return different values. Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: Hi @plausibly_exogenous, please find above my edit to answer your comment. Hope this is what you were looking for ;-) Cheers.

Comment: It is! Thanks so much. Checkmarked.

Comment: Hi @plausibly_exogenous, I saw that you preferred to validate the answer of Merijn van Tilborg. This is your choice and I respect it without any problem. Note however that the answer you have just validated is 7.8 times slower than the one I suggest; and at the end of your question you seem to indicate that you want a fast efficient solution.

Comment: Hi @lovalery. Sorry, I am not super well informed about the etiquette about validating. I usually just checkmark recent solutions that work well, and are succinct. But I now realize that this is sort of arbitrary and can be perceived as being rude. Apologies. I've restored your checkmark. Thank you for your continued contributions.

Comment: Hi @plausibly_exogenous. Thanks for your reply and no worries there is no problem at all. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should see if the slider package works for you.  It can both cut the data by rows, but also apply functions like the apply / purrr functionality.

```
library(tibble)
library(slider)
library(dplyr)

f <- data.frame(date = c(as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:03:04"), 
         as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:07:03"), as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:15:23"),
         as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:16:28"), as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:21:30"), 
         as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:22:03"), as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:25:23"),
         as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:36:28"), as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:41:30"), 
         as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:47:03"), as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:48:23"),
         as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:51:28"), as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:51:30"), 
         as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:57:03"), as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:61:23"),
         as.POSIXlt("2019-01-01 00:66:28"))) %>% arrange(date)

g <- block(f, f$date, period = "minute", every=15)
```

Comment: Why do you need `as.POSIXlt` for each element? just do `f <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXlt(c(....)))`

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. I think your 5th row should be group 2, since it is before `00:30:00` of the day. Please clarify if this is incorrect.
2. You say it needs to be per-day, but your data only includes one day; I'll augment it to demonstrate its per-day calculations.

```r
DT[,date := as.POSIXct(date)]
DT2 <- rbindlist(list(DT, DT[, date := date + 86400]))
DT2
#                    date   grp
#                  <POSc> <int>
#  1: 2019-01-02 00:03:04     1
#  2: 2019-01-02 00:07:03     1
#  3: 2019-01-02 00:15:23     2
#  4: 2019-01-02 00:16:28     2
#  5: 2019-01-02 00:21:30     2
#  6: 2019-01-02 00:03:04     1
#  7: 2019-01-02 00:07:03     1
#  8: 2019-01-02 00:15:23     2
#  9: 2019-01-02 00:16:28     2
# 10: 2019-01-02 00:21:30     2
```

And the group-assignment:

```r
DT2[, day := format(date, format = "%Y%m%d")
  ][, grp := findInterval(date, seq(lubridate::floor_date(min(date), unit = "hours"), max(date) + 3600, by = "15 mins")), by = day][]
#                    date   grp      day
#                  <POSc> <int>   <char>
#  1: 2019-01-02 00:03:04     1 20190102
#  2: 2019-01-02 00:07:03     1 20190102
#  3: 2019-01-02 00:15:23     2 20190102
#  4: 2019-01-02 00:16:28     2 20190102
#  5: 2019-01-02 00:21:30     2 20190102
#  6: 2019-01-02 00:03:04     1 20190102
#  7: 2019-01-02 00:07:03     1 20190102
#  8: 2019-01-02 00:15:23     2 20190102
#  9: 2019-01-02 00:16:28     2 20190102
# 10: 2019-01-02 00:21:30     2 20190102
```

Comment: Hi @r2evans, yes you are right that it should be group 2. Thank you for your solution. I tested it, and it works great. Thank you for your consistent help.

Comment: @r2evans, using data.table and lubridate there are more powerful ways to do so and can be reduced to a single oneliner where all is done in the by clause. `DT[, date_15min_grp := .GRP, by = format(floor_date(ymd_hms(date), "15 minutes"), "%H:%M:%S")]`

Comment: I'm not as proficient with `.GRP`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT <- data.table(date = c("2019-01-01 00:03:04", 
                          "2019-01-01 00:07:03",
                          "2019-01-01 00:15:23",
                          "2019-01-01 00:16:28",
                          "2019-01-01 00:21:30"))

# if every new day falls in a new group
DT[, date_15min_grp := .GRP, by = floor_date(ymd_hms(date), "15 minutes")]

# if every new day needs to fall in the same group
DT[, date_15min_grp := .GRP, by = format(floor_date(ymd_hms(date), "15 minutes"), "%H:%M:%S")]
```

Comment: This solution works, and is also very succinct. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner with my santoku package:

```r
DT$date <- as.POSIXct(DT$date)
DT$interval <- santoku::chop_width(DT$date, minutes(15))
DT
##                   date                                   interval
## 1: 2019-01-01 00:03:04 [2019-01-01 00:03:04, 2019-01-01 00:18:04)
## 2: 2019-01-01 00:07:03 [2019-01-01 00:03:04, 2019-01-01 00:18:04)
## 3: 2019-01-01 00:15:23 [2019-01-01 00:03:04, 2019-01-01 00:18:04)
## 4: 2019-01-01 00:16:28 [2019-01-01 00:03:04, 2019-01-01 00:18:04)
## 5: 2019-01-01 00:21:30 [2019-01-01 00:18:04, 2019-01-01 00:33:04)
```

Labels can be customized, e.g. try `chop_width(DT$date, minutes(15), labels = lbl_dash(fmt = "%H:%M:%S"))`